# Pass deeplink through google play on first app install

Tags: android, deep-linking

I am trying to implement the scenario that is defined in following link:

https://support.google.com/adwords/answer/6310665

The user, who doesn't have the app, should be prompted to install it - then he/she should continue to the screen in the app via deep linking.

I have my deeplink like following and I added this in a simple html document and opening it on Chrome:

android-app://com.example.android/exampleapp/productid_1234

It works at start as expected, the store will be opened and I install the app. Then when I start the app via open button on the app install page, I do not get deep link, in this case exampleapp/productid_1234, passed to my app.

```
Uri fullUri = getIntent().getData();
```

I have following intent filter for my activity, this activity is also my launcher activity.

```
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.VIEW" />
            <category android:name="android.intent.category.DEFAULT" />
            <category android:name="android.intent.category.BROWSABLE" />
            <data android:scheme="exampleapp" />
        </intent-filter>
```

When I quit the app and click on the link on Chrome again, in this case I got the deep link in my app.

Any help will be appreciated.

Comment: This is called 'deferred deep linking', and it's rather complicated with a ton of edge cases. Sounds like either you're running into one of these, or something in your configuration isn't set up quite right. You could try a free service like [Branch.io](https://branch.io) (full disclosure: I'm on the team) to help with some of the technical backend

Comment: What are those edge cases? What can be wrong with my configuration? Isn't it possible doing this without an extra service?

Comment: Things like device type, OS version, app in which the link is opened, etc. It definitely is possible to do this without using an extra service, but it is often a lot of extra work

Comment: Can you provide me a tutorial for this? In first case I want to definitely give it a try before I use an extra service. Thanks for your help